# How to recognize that CyanogenMod is on a board?

Tags: android, firmware, cyanogenmod

I have checked a lot of fields from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html .

However I am not able to get clearly information that specific device use CyanogenMod.

this is what I get:

```
NETWORK_TYPE="0"
SDK_INT="10"
CODENAME="REL"
INCREMENTAL="eng.android.20110308.014205"
RELEASE="2.3.3"
SDK="10"
Build.BOARD=bravo
BOOTLOADER=0.93.0001
BRAND=htc_wwe
CPU_ABI=armeabi-v7a
CPU_ABI2=armeabi
DEVICE=bravo
DISPLAY=GRI40
FINGERPRINT=htc_wwe/htc_bravo/bravo/bravo:2.2/FRF91/226611:user/release-keys
HARDWARE=bravo
HOST=giulio-desktop
ID=FRF91
MANUFACTURER=HTC
MODEL=HTC Desire
PRODUCT=htc_bravo
RADIO=unknown
TAGS=release-keys
TIME=0
TYPE=userdebug
USER=android
```

---

```
NETWORK_TYPE="0"
SDK_INT="10"
CODENAME="REL"
INCREMENTAL="eng.shade.20110307.195429"
RELEASE="2.3.3"
SDK="10"
Build.BOARD=mahimahi
BOOTLOADER=0.35.0017
BRAND=google
CPU_ABI=armeabi-v7a
CPU_ABI2=armeabi
DEVICE=passion
DISPLAY=GRI40
FINGERPRINT=google/passion/passion:2.3.3/GRI40/102588:user/release-keys
HARDWARE=mahimahi
HOST=toxygene
ID=GRI40
MANUFACTURER=HTC
MODEL=Nexus One
PRODUCT=passion
RADIO=unknown
TAGS=test-keys
TIME=0
TYPE=user
USER=shade
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way which I found is to read file /proc/version, which contain information about kernel version.

Phones with cyanogenmod give something like:

```
Linux version 2.6.37.2-cyanogenmod-01149-g8cdf03e
```

reading this file not requires root privileges (runnung `uname -r` does).

Comment: This isn't the most robust answer as anyone can change out their kernel which would cause this answer to fail.

Comment: I get this error when I try to read `/proc/version` on Android 9: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/version (Permission denied)`

Answer (score 6):

`PackageManager.hasSystemFeature("com.cyanogenmod.android")` will be more consistent.

Comment: Where did you hear this is the most consistent method?

Comment: "System Feature" is a unique name with exact meaning, thus unlikely to change unintentionally.

Answer (score 3):

It's a lot easier to read it from the system properties:

```
String version = System.getProperty("os.version");
if (version.contains("cyanogenmod")) {
    isCyanogenMode = true;
}
```

On my device, `os.version` is `2.6.37.6-cyanogenmod-01509-g8913be8`

Alternatively, you could also rely on the [Build.USER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#USER) constant, which carries the name of the person who assembled the build. For CyanogenMod, this is often "shade" (another nickname of Steve Kondik aka Cyanogen).

There is also a special property `ro.modversion`, but as far as I can see you would need access to the [SystemProperties](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/ics/core/java/android/os/SystemProperties.java) internal class in order to read it programmatically.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get `System.getProperty("os.version")` gives me `3.4.0-g9c0baa9`.

Answer (score 1):

On my device `System.getProperty("os.version")` is something like `3.0.64-CM-g9d16c8a`. Checking for `cyanogenmod` in the version number does not work anymore. I have added more details in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800671/does-android-have-any-way-to-detect-cyanogenmod-and-its-version/25050609#25050609).

Answer (score 0):

The kernel gets swapped out all the time by end users so using System.getProperty("os.version") or reading from /proc/version are not good indicators of whether the device is running cyanogenmod. Let me rephrase, using those solely as the indicator is not a good idea. You'll need to use a combination of methods. As @kakopappa indicated in his other post where he reads os.version and /proc/version you should also check

```
android.os.Build.HOST
```

From my experience that has contained cyanogenmod in it 9 times out of 10. Just to be safe you'll want to use the other methods as well though since the HOST variable could be changed via build.prop -> ro.build.host