# Does Android have any way to detect cyanogenmod and its version?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an android media player which needs equalizer. However, equalizer is only available on Gingerbread and above, but cyanogenmod 6 has modified audioflinger to act as equalizer, so I want to detect OS version.

Comment: By the way, this question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499217/how-to-recognize-that-cyanogenmod-is-on-a-board

Comment: maybe cyanogenmod have their own class in framework, so how about use reflecting? or detect audioflinger version?I'm making an application for normal user, using uname is totally not a good idea

Comment: I've updated my answer with the correct approach. You can read the `os.version` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the `os.version` property and match against that:

```
String version = System.getProperty("os.version");
if (version.contains("cyanogenmod")) {
    isCyanogenMode = true;
}
```

On my device, `os.version` is `2.6.37.6-cyanogenmod-01509-g8913be8`.

Comment: I've posted a more exhaustive answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9801191/127013

Comment: Can I prevent installations of my app on cyanogenmod?

Answer (score 4):

As of today, cyanogenmod's kernel does not contain `cyanogenmod` keyword in `System.getProperty("os.version");` It is something like `3.0.64-CM-g9d16c8a`. So I wrote this function.

```
private boolean isCyanogenMod(PackageManager pm) {
    boolean isCyanogenMod = false;
    String version = System.getProperty("os.version");
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        if (version.contains("cyanogenmod") || pm.hasSystemFeature("com.cyanogenmod.android")) {
            isCyanogenMod = true;
        }
        else {                
            // This does not require root
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/version"), 256);
            version = reader.readLine();

            if (version.contains("cyanogenmod")) {
                isCyanogenMod = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if(reader != null) {
            try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

    return isCyanogenMod;
}
```

Comment: os.version and the kernel version aren't good indicators. The kernel can be swapped out easily and happens very often by users which affects both of these properties. The best solution is to use Build.HOST from my experience.

Comment: I get this error when I try to read `/proc/version` on Android 9: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/version (Permission denied)`

Answer (score 2):

Well this is an old question, but I have recently come up with a better solution I believe.

```
public static boolean isCyanogenMod() {
    try {
        return Class.forName("cyanogenmod.os.Build") != null;
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
    return false;
}
```