# How many users are on custom ROMs

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

Does anybody know a good resource that shows roughly how many users out there have custom ROMs?  It would be great to see a breakdown by custom ROM type too.

It seems like it would involve detecting all the different device/OS identifiers (e.g. [for Cyanogen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9800828/112705)), so I was hoping somebody might have done this already.

The reason I care is that my in-app camera causes some Cyanogen devices to immediately reboot if the user takes a photo with their front facing camera (looks like a [known issue](https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/CYAN-1504) in Cyanogen).  This happens before my crash reporting frameworks can even run.

Comment: As a developer you can't be held responsible for what happens on rooted devices. I understand your position, but rooting voids any and all warranties, contracts, it's now in the users hands.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  However, if it affects a significant number of my users and I have the ability to workaround the issues, then I would consider it.  That's why I'd like to know how widely they are used.

Answer (score 1):

If CyanogenMod has 9 million, then I'd venture MIUI has about 2 million, and add another 2 million for (AOKP, PA, Slim, Omni, ChaOS, and stock modded roms).

So I'd say 12-15 million, as not many enable stat reporting. I don't know the stat websites for other roms, but they exist out there.

http://stats.cyanogenmod.com/